# Azure storage account location with Recovery Services vault location

Tags: azure, backup, diagnostics

I am setting up Azure Backup report, I have a Recovery Service Vault in Canada East, and a storage account located in Canada Central.   when I try to pick up storage location for Backup report, there is none.  It looks like you only can choose storage account at the same location with Recovery Service Vault.

Is this a bug? Do I have to create another storage account in Canada East?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is by designed, see this link: [Supported scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-configure-reports#supported-scenarios).

> You can view reports across vaults and subscriptions, if the same storage account is configured for each of the vaults. **The storage account selected must be in the same region as the Recovery Services vault.**

Comment: Thank you,   I did miss this part